# Why PHP can convert %2B to empty string instead of +?

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I am runing Laravel 5.3 application on PHP buildin-server and trying to perform following request:

`api/people?sort=%2Bname`

I expect that `%2B` will be converted to `+`, but for some reasons, it doesn't happen:

`$request->input('sort') => " name"`

Can such behaviour be related to PHP settings?

Answer (score 0):

Seems a PHP thing, test it with:

`print_r(rawurldecode($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']));//Result:content=+name`

and

`print_r(urldecode($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']));//Result:content= name`

Workaround:

```
$result=array();
array_map(function($a) use (&$result){
              $a=explode('=',$a);        
              $result[$a[0]]=$a[1];
},explode('&',rawurldecode($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])));

print_r($result);
```